# Why does the assembler not resolve "LENGTH * TYPEOF SomeArray

Tags: assembly, x86, typeof, masm32

```
ARRAY_LENGTH = 8
Array DWORD ARRAY_LENGTH DUP(0)
...
MOV eax, ARRAY_LENGTH * 4
  ;Does get executed, however
MOV eax, ARRAY_LENGTH * TYPEOF Array
  ;Does not
```

I really wonder why. I cant find it anywhere, thus am asking it the experts :-)

Comment: Don't you want `SIZEOF` rather than `TYPEOF` ?

Comment: As suggested by @PaulR, use `mov eax,SIZEOF Array` instead (or just `SIZE Array`, or `ARRAY_LENGTH * SIZEOF TYPE Array` if you like to type lots of characters).

Comment: Of course I could use `SIZEOF` anytime. However, that does not answer my question: why can't the assembler resolve `ARRAY_LENGTH * TYPEOF Array` since `TYPEOF something` is also a constant (in this case 4).

Comment: I'm not sure where you found `TYPEOF`. It's not listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk35xcha.aspx), nor in the `masm32.chm` document that comes with masm32. And none of the libraries that come with masm32 appear to use it.

Comment: Uhm.... Now I am ashamed. Sorry Paul and Michael. Yea, it should have been `TYPE` (or `SIZEOF` for that matter) - And then it does build. Now it is all clear to me - I guess it was late yesterday. Thanks both of you ;-)